# Warning when setting up a unique backup on external HDD Windows Server Backup 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-backup

I want to do an external backup for my Hyper-V server, running on Windows Server 2016.
For that, I use Windows Server Backup, and an external hard drive (10To) LaCie, formatted in NTFS, connected with USB.

When I try to launch a single backup and when I have to choose the destination, I select the external HDD, but got a warning : "The save destination is on the same hard drive that your exploitation system. In case of breakdown, you may lose your server datas and backup datas. Do you want to continue ?"

I don't understand why he keep warning me since it is an external drive.

Do I have to configure the external drive ? How can I do it ?

Comment: It's difficult to tell since you haven't provided any information, please clarify your question by editing it after reading the guidelines: [ask]